# Why does C# compiler overload resolution algorithm treat static and instance members with equal signature as equal?

Tags: c#, .net, static-members, overload-resolution

Let we have two members equal by signature, but one is static and another - is not:

```
class Foo
{
    public void Test() { Console.WriteLine("instance"); }

    public static void Test() { Console.WriteLine("static"); }
}
```

but such code generate brings a compiler error:

> Type 'Foo' already defines a member called 'Test' with the same parameter types

But why?

Let we compiled that successfully, then:

- `Foo.Test()` should output "static"
- `new Foo().Test();`should output "instance"

Can't call the static member instead of instance one because in this case another, more reasonable compiler error will occur:

> Member 'Foo.Test()' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What about, from an instance method:

```
Test();
```

What would that call? You'd probably want to give the instance method "priority" over the static method, but both would be applicable.

I would say that even if it were allowed, it would be a fundamentally bad idea to do this from a readability point of view... for example, if you changed a method which called `Test` from being static to instance, it would change the meaning in a subtle way.

In other words, I have no problem with this being prohibited :)

Comment: In that case the compiler should enforce you using either this.Test() or Foo.Test(). Your argumentation also applies to instance variables vs. parameters, which may also have naming comflicts.

Comment: @codymanix: I think I'm still happier for this to just be prohibited. I find it relatively rare for the same method to make sense (with the same parameters) as both an instance and static method...

Comment: @codymanix: +1 but i think i understood why is it prohibited: let we have a such class and it compiles fine; and another two - one with instance method, and another with static. From declaration point of view all 3 are equal. But from usage - not: first will require additional code to resolve the ambiguity while 2 others - not. That's not good.

Comment: Jon, thank you for use case that exposes the possible issue. I also had no problem until I have to mock a factory with static-only methods: I can't add an instance-method returning the same. So have to invent a bicycle :)